# Homogeneous first order ODE with partial fractions solution help

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, proof-verification, problem-solving

I am not sure where I went wrong. I am very confident my algebra is fine and I set up my partial fractions exactly as I was supposed to. I am not sure what is wrong.

$(x^2-y^2)\frac{dy}{dx}=2xy$

of course $v=\frac{y}{x}$ and $y=xv$ and $y' = v+\frac{dv}{dx}$

using y = xv:

$v + x \frac{dv}{dx} = \frac{2x^2v}{x^2-x^2v^2}$

$v + x\frac{dv}{dx} = \frac{2v}{1-v^2}$

subtracting V over:

$x\frac{dv}{dx} = \frac{2v}{1-v^2}-\frac{v(1-v^2)}{1-v^2}$

$x\frac{dv}{dx} = \frac{2v-(v(1-v^2))}{1-v^2}$

$x\frac{dv}{dx} = \frac{2v-(v-v^2)}{1-v^2}$

$x\frac{dv}{dx} = \frac{v+v^3}{1-v^2}$

$\int \frac{1-v^2}{v(1+v^2)}dv = \int \frac{dx}{x}$

LHS: $\frac{A}{v}+\frac{Bx+c}{1+v^2}$

$A(1+v^2)+(Bv+C)v$

$1-v^2 = A + Av^2+ Bv^2 + Cv$

equating coefficients:

$-v^2 : -1 = B+A$

$0 = Cv \to C = 0$

$1 = A$ so $-1 = B + 1 \to B = -2$

$\int \frac{1}{v}dv + \frac{-2}{1+v^2} = \int \frac{dx}{x}$

$\int \frac{1}{v} dv + -2\int \frac{1}{1+v^2}dv = \int \frac{dx}{x}$

$ln \vert v \vert -2arctan{v} = ln \vert x \vert + C$

After using the answer:

After getting $ln \vert v \vert - ln \vert 1+v^2 \vert$

I cannot get to the answer

$y = C(x^2 + y^2)$

my attempt multiply both sides by $e$ and obtain:

$v - 1 - v^2 = x + C$

one gets absorbed with C:

$v-v^2= x + C$

$\frac{y}{x} - \frac{y^2}{x^2} = x+ C$

I've tried multiplying x over, Ive tried subtracting x nothing seems to work..

Comment: arctan maybe the partial fractions but It is a similar set up to a problem that I saw it had $(z^2+1)$ and was setup as $\frac{Bx+C}{z^2+1}$

Comment: I certainly cant solve for y in this set up

Comment: so $v - e^{-2arctan(v)} = x + c$

Comment: really? symbolab told me it was arctan for some reason

Comment: where did you get positive 2?

Comment: I am confused by your set up

Comment: so what did I do wrong in solving for B?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your partial fraction set up is
\begin{align*}
\frac{1-v^2}{v(1+v^2)}&=\frac{A}{v}+\frac{B\color{red}{v}+C}{1+v^2}
\end{align*}

Then you got the values as $A=1, B=-2$ and $C=0$. This means
\begin{align*}
\frac{1-v^2}{v(1+v^2)}&=\frac{1}{v}-\frac{2\color{red}{v}}{1+v^2}
\end{align*}
Now when you integrate you get
\begin{align*}
\int \frac{1-v^2}{v(1+v^2)} \, dv & =\int \frac{1}{v} \, dv-\int \frac{2\color{red}{v}}{1+v^2}\,dv\\
&=\ln |v |-\ln|1+v^2|+C.
\end{align*}